# When using jsonlite in R, how to specify manually which are treated as arrays? The auto_unbox doesn't work in this case

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I have the following code:

```
data = list(
    "id" = equip_id,
    "initial_date" = 1608433200,
    "final_date" = 1609038000,
    "limit" = 10000,
    "order" = "asc",
    "properties" = "forecast"
)
```

If I use:

```
jsonlite::toJSON(data, auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

I have this:

```
{"id":3,"initial_date":1608433200,"final_date":1609038000,"limit":10000,"order":"asc","properties":"forecast"}
```

But what I want:

```
{"id":3,"initial_date":1608433200,"final_date":1609038000,"limit":10000,"order":"asc","properties":["forecast"]}
```

How can I edit manually which one are arrays or not?

Comment: What is `equip_id`.  Can you add that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `properties` to a list:

```
data = list(
    "id" = equip_id,
    "initial_date" = 1608433200,
    "final_date" = 1609038000,
    "limit" = 10000,
    "order" = "asc",
    "properties" = list("forecast")
)
```